# Azure DevOps: Pipeline is not getting triggered automatically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, .net-6.0

I have created .Net 6 project and stored the source code in GitHub. When I push my changes then the pipeline build is not triggering or building automatically, what would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to -> Pipeline -> Edit Pipeline -> Trigger -> click the check box name "Enable the Continues Intergration " and then Save.